# Tkinter Multiple window not Opening on button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

On click of the button clk the first instance of the window opens but after destroying the first window, the successive windows does not open. Only after the main instance win is closed the successive windows open.

```
from tkinter import *

def func():
    root = Tk()
    b1 = Button(root,text='Click Me!').pack()
    root.after(2000, lambda: root.destroy())
    root.mainloop()

    root=Tk()
    b1 = Button(root,text='Click Me!',bg='orange').pack()
    root.mainloop()

win = Tk()
clk = Button(win,text='func',command=func).pack()
win.mainloop()
```

There is no syntax error, but I'm not getting the output that I want.

Thank You

Comment: You shouldn't call `Tk()` more than once in a program (use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows), and you shouldn't need to call `mainloop()` more than once.

Comment: BTW: `clk = Button(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `clk` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` always returns `None`. If you need `clk` then you should do it in two steps `clk = Button(...)` and `clk.pack()`

Answer (score 1):

At best of my understanding there can be only one mainloop(). I rewrote your code to make it work.

```
from tkinter import *

def func():
    root = Toplevel()
    b1 = Button(root,text='Click Me!').pack()
    root.after(2000, lambda: second(root))

def second(root):
    root.destroy()
    root=Toplevel()
    b1 = Button(root,text='Click Me!',bg='orange').pack()

win = Tk()
clk = Button(win,text='func',command=func).pack()
win.mainloop()
```